# SQL Syntax Error - Can't Import

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have been trying to import this query but it doesn't seem to work?

```
-- --------------------------------------------------------
-- Host:                         127.0.0.1
-- Server versie:                10.1.21-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution
-- Server OS:                    Win64
-- HeidiSQL Versie:              9.3.0.4984
-- --------------------------------------------------------

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;

-- Databasestructuur van gta5_gamemode_essential wordt geschreven
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `gta5_gamemode_essential` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 */;
USE `gta5_gamemode_essential`;


-- Structuur van  tabel gta5_gamemode_essential.bans wordt geschreven
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bans` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `banned` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `banner` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `reason` varchar(150) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `expires` datetime NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- Data exporteren was gedeselecteerd


-- Structuur van  tabel gta5_gamemode_essential.users wordt geschreven
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `identifier` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `group` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `permission_level` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `money` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `weapons` varchar(5000) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `personalvehicle` varchar(10000) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `withdraw_cost` int(10) NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- Data exporteren was gedeselecteerd
/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=IFNULL(@OLD_SQL_MODE, '') */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=IF(@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS IS NULL, 1, @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS) */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
```

Comment: What database are you running it in? MySql or Sql-Server?

Comment: The error would be helpful

Comment: The error message(s) you get will tell you what problem is causing it not to work. Without it, we can't really offer any answers. Please __edit your question__ and add the full error message.

Answer (score 0):

```
  `withdraw_cost` int(10) NOT NULL,   -- Remove this comma
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

`users` needs a `PRIMARY KEY`.  Or maybe you are missing the `PRIMARY KEY` clause??